# Collection with sub- collection

Tags: vb.net, collections

Lets suppose I have forum with one thread with 3 posts.

I want to get this  final result:

```
Dim MyFourm As new Fourm
MyFourm.Thread.Add(545)''for ex 545 mean Thread ID.

MyForum.Thread(0).Post(1).Username
```

Thread should be collection of integer(=Thread ID)
Post should be collection of Post type

So in this case, the code say something like "chose first thread, and the second post and retrieve username of who write this post"

```
Public Class Fourm
'Thread should be inside this class and do some background code
End Class

Public Class Post
Public Property Username as string
Public Property PostContent as string
End Class
```

Just to be a clear: The goal is to organize the collections. Each Thread should have with his own posts.

I chose Forum at an example, but it could be anything else ..
If I do not clear please help me .. This is not my native language(But do not worry - I can read. ;))

Comment: If the `Thread` is a collection with integers it can't contain posts. You have to use a collection of `Thread` where each `Thread`  instance has a collection of `Post`. Another approach is to use a `Dictionary(Of Int32, List(Of Post))`. So the key is the threadid and the value is the list with all posts.

Answer (score 0):

In my correct project iam using Dictionary. I just want to explore some more..
Anyway, I tried what you say about "You have to use a collection of Thread where each Thread instance has a collection of Post"
and this is the result:

```
Public Class MainFrm
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim MyForum As New Forum
        MyForum.Thread.Add(500)' some id's
        MyForum.Thread.Add(120) 

        MyForum.Thread(0).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 500 | Post: 1#", .Username = "Don"})
        MyForum.Thread(0).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 500 | Post: 2#", .Username = "Shon"})
        MyForum.Thread(0).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 500 | Post: 3#", .Username = "Ron"})

        MyForum.Thread(1).Posts.Add(New ForumPost() With {.PostContent = "Therad ID: 120 | Post 1#", .Username = "Emi"})


        For iThread = 0 To MyForum.Thread.Count - 1
            For iPost = 0 To MyForum.Thread(iThread).Posts.Count - 1
                Static Pst As New ForumPost
                Pst = MyForum.Thread(iThread).Posts(iPost)
                Console.WriteLine($"Content:{Pst.PostContent}, Username who post it:{Pst.Username}")
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Forum
    Public Property Thread As New ThreadCollection

End Class

Public Class ForumThread
    Inherits List(Of Integer)
    Public Property Posts As New PostCollection
    Sub New(id As Integer)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ThreadCollection
    Inherits List(Of ForumThread)
    Public Overloads Sub Add(ByVal id As Integer)
        MyBase.Add(New ForumThread(id))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ForumPost
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property PostContent As String
End Class

Public Class PostCollection
    Inherits List(Of ForumPost)
End Class



 '   Content:Therad ID: 500 | Post: 1#, Username who post it:Don
 '  Content:Therad ID: 500 | Post: 2#, Username who post it:Shon
 '  Content:Therad ID: 500 | Post: 3#, Username who post it:Ron
 '   Content:Therad ID: 120 | Post 1#, Username who post it:Emi
```

**Now my question is: This supposed to be like this? Or there is a better way to write this?**